# 21.04 doesn't fully suspend

Tags: suspend, 21.04

I am a new Linux user and recently installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my PC. At first, suspend worked properly and would only start back up when I pressed the power button. Now it just goes back to the login screen and keeps running.

I tried searching for fixes, but most suspend questions are about laptops and I could't find one about this specific problem.

Comment: Smells like a possible crash. Look in your syslog and /var/crash for clues. You cannot "fix" it if you do not understand the actual problem.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Sorry it has been so long, I haven't had time to devote to this issue last month. I tried suspending again and looked for a crash report and did not find one. I was able to locate my syslog, but I am not sure what else to look for. When I tried to suspend it the screen went blank for a moment and then immediately went to the login screen.